# CFFI - Is Python callback for C code possible in ABI mode?

Tags: python, python-cffi

I need a provide a callback for C code. Basically, I need this to work:

In C:

```
typedef int callback_t(int i);
callback_t *callback = NULL;
```

in Python:

```
from cffi import FFI

def py_callback(i):
    return 0

ffi_builder = FFI()
lib = ffi_builder.dlopen('foobar.so')
lib.callback = py_callback
```

Adding `@ffi_builder.def_extern()` to `py_callback` throws an exception: `ffi.def_extern() is only available on API-mode FFI objects`.

So is it possible in ABI mode at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need [old-style callbacks](http://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#callbacks-old-style).